# How to run the functions at the same time on @onsubmit in a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a form using HTML5, JavaScript, PHP and CSS. However this question is about the first two.

My HTML:

```
<form name="register" action="register.php" method="POST" onsubmit="if (submitCheck(this) && genderCheck()){this.submit();} else {return false;}">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br />
            <label id="warning_first"></label>
            <br />
            <label>Surname:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"><br />
            <label id="warning_second"></label>
            <br />
            <label>Gender:</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male">Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other">Other
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Prefer not to say"> Prefer not to say <br />
            <label id="warning_third"></label>
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel();">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
```

And my javascript:

```
function submitCheck() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    function firstNameCheck() {
        if (firstName.length !== 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("warning_first").innerHTML = "This is required!";
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (lastName.length !== 0 && firstNameCheck()) {
            document.getElementById("warning_first").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("warning_second").innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        } else if (lastName.length !== 0 && firstNameCheck() !== true) {
            document.getElementById("warning_first").innerHTML = "This is required!";
            document.getElementById("warning_second").innerHTML = "";
            return false;
        } else if (lastName.length === 0 && firstNameCheck()) {
            document.getElementById("warning_second").innerHTML = "This is required!";
            document.getElementById("warning_first").innerHTML = "";
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("warning_second").innerHTML = "This is required!";
            document.getElementById("warning_first").innerHTML = "This is required!";
            return false;
    }
}

function genderCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById("male").checked) {
        document.getElementById("warning_third").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("warning_third").innerHTML = "This is required!";
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I press submit the onsubmit part executes and checks but when I leave all fields blank, the "This is required" message only appears for the first two and not for gender radio buttons. How can I fix this?

Comment: There is no need to put an if query into elements attribute `onSubmit`. This way is always a good source for errors. Create a single function that collects all nessecary states and return true or false.

Comment: Another on: To check  a length of a String `!=`or `== `is enough.

Comment: @reporter ,should I check all of the things in one function in the onSubmit? How would I do this?

Comment: Create a function that contains a "central boolean value". Think about about when a submit is allowed and when not and put your tests in there. The goal is: return true the submit will be triggerd, and return false the submit won't be triggerd by browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason only `submitCheck()` executes is because that is how AND operator behaves.

Explanation :

The AND(&&) operator does the following:

- Evaluates operands from left to right.
- For each operand, converts it to a boolean. If the result is false, stops and returns the original value of that operand.
- If all operands have been evaluated (i.e. all were truthy), returns the last operand.

In other words, AND returns the first falsy value or the last value if none were found.

Work around for this:

HTML page:

```
<form name="register" action="register.php" method="POST" onsubmit="if(finalcheck()){submit();} else {return false;}">
<label>First Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br />
<label id="warning_first"></label>
<br />
<label>Surname:</label>
<input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"><br />
<label id="warning_second"></label>
<br />
<label>Gender:</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other">Other
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Prefer not to say"> Prefer not to say <br />
<label id="warning_third"></label>
<br />
<input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="cancel();">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

JavaScript Page :

```
function submitCheck() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;

    function firstNameCheck() {
        if (firstName.length !== 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("warning_first").innerHTML = "This is required!";
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (lastName.length !== 0 && firstNameCheck()) {
            document.getElementById("warning_first").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("warning_second").innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        } else if (lastName.length !== 0 && firstNameCheck() !== true) {
            document.getElementById("warning_first").innerHTML = "This is required!";
            document.getElementById("warning_second").innerHTML = "";
            return false;
        } else if (lastName.length === 0 && firstNameCheck()) {
            document.getElementById("warning_second").innerHTML = "This is required!";
            document.getElementById("warning_first").innerHTML = "";
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("warning_second").innerHTML = "This is required!";
            document.getElementById("warning_first").innerHTML = "This is required!";
            return false;
    }

}

function genderCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById("male").checked) {
        document.getElementById("warning_third").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("warning_third").innerHTML = "This is required!";
        return false;
    }
}

function finalcheck(){
    submitCheck();
    genderCheck();

    if(submitCheck() && genderCheck()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

*Note :

- Mostly you would know about this but if not you don't then you can explore "required" option in input tag.
- You should modularize function well and also check the gender radio group, you have given id value only for one input.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the "required" attribute on an input tag. This has greatly simplified it for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of iterating over your radio buttons and check if at least one of those is selected.

Of course this can be done in different ways. All your radio buttons have the name attribute set to **gender**. Javascript offers a powerful function to get a **nodeList** - essentially an array - of all the elements with the same name: **getElementsByName(name)**

So let's modify your genderCheck function a little bit:

```
var elements=document.getElementsByName("gender");
```

elements now holds a nodelist of all the radio buttons. A HTML radio button has a special property called **.checked**, which if queried - that particular radio button is indeed checked - returns true.
So let's iterate over the nodeList and check if at least one of the nodes checked propery is true:

```
  var checked = false;
  for (var a = 0; a < elements.length; a++) {
    if (elements[a].checked) {
      checked = true;
    }
  }
```

Now we can reuse your existing code to write a message if we found a checked radio button or not:

```
  if (checked) {
    document.getElementById("warning_third").innerHTML = "";
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("warning_third").innerHTML = "This is required!";
    return false;
  }
```

So to complete function looks like this:

```
function genderCheck() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByName("gender");
  var checked = false;
  for (var a = 0; a < elements.length; a++) {
    if (elements[a].checked) {
      checked = true;
    }
  }
  if (checked) {
    document.getElementById("warning_third").innerHTML = "";
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("warning_third").innerHTML = "This is required!";
    return false;
  }
}
```